# What is the difference between Uchi-Mata and Hane-Goshi?

Tags: technique, judo, terminology, throwing

Classical *uchi-mata* involves reaping uke's back leg up and twisting them over their grounded off-balanced leg. However a common competition variant involves loading uke on tori's waist and reaping through the middle of uke's legs / against their far leg, effectively lifting with the hips before turning to throw.

How is this technique distinguished from *hane-goshi*?

Answer (score 1):

For the *koshi-waza* style uchi-mata, what distinguishes it from *hane-goshi* is the position of the leg (whether straight through uke's legs, or bent):

> In the original uchi-mata, tori sweeps up uke's left leg with his right leg, which brings it under ashi-waza techniques.  But increasingly, we see a kind of koshi-waza technique where tori loads uke onto his waist and sweeps him up.
> #> Consequently, uchi-mata is classified under both ashi-waza and koshi-waza, but the koshi-waza type of uchi-mata described here is a practical technique.
>
> This technique is similar to hane-goshi. If tori scoops uke up using the waist and leg, from a posture with his right knee bent, it is then classified as hane-goshi (photo 37).
>
> | [image: uchi mata] | [image: hane goshi] |
> | --- | --- |
> | "koshi-waza" uchi-mata | hane-goshi |

- [Kodokan Judo Throwing Techniques](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/KODOKAN_JUDO_THROWING_TECHNIQUES/HGpbICBZdGwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22classified+as+hane-goshi%22), Toshiro Daigo (2005)

Note the *Kodokan New Japanese-English Dictionary of Judo* makes allusion to the overlap between these two techniques:

> haneru **(to spring/jump)** A situation in which the powerful effect of a hane goshi or uchimata sends your opponent's body high into the air.

Answer (score 1):

You can distinguish between uchi mata (内股) and hane goshi (springing hip) (跳腰) by examining the action of tori's hips.

- In hane goshi, tori's hips displace uke's hips. This is the hip spring described in the technique name. I think it's easiest to do this if tori's hips are perpendicular to uke's hips.

  [I can imagine a one-legged tori being able to perform throw hane goshi in this manner.](https://www.reddit.com/r/judo/comments/f6uviy/trying_one_step_hanegoshi/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) The leg contact is incidental and there is no power if tori tries to lift their leg out to the side.
- In uchi mata, tori bends at the hips and tori's leg reaps uke's leg. If tori attacks the near leg, everyone sees the traditional uchi mata, but [tori can perform the same body motion to attack the far leg and it's still an uchi mata (内股)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYd7h64bBjY).

  I think it's easiest to perform this action if tori's leg is going straight back into the target leg, which makes tori's hips face basically the same direction as uke's hips.

These are the two examples I think most clearly illustrate the two principles. The principles can be mixed however, in which case I'm personally no longer interested where the line between the two techniques should be be drawn.

[The Kodokan has recently started a series of videos for judo pedants for Kodokan throw classification](https://youtu.be/IqhpUWgAZYk), but this one has not been published yet.